# Styled component with conditional calc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Currently I have the value being passed from the component

```
    <Img $marginTop= {entry?.intersectionRatio} src={imgUrl} alt="" />
```

The code below is a simple statemnt which check if $marginTop is true (not null), then it should calculate `calc($marginTop*-10)vh`, else it should set margin-top as 0px. But the code below seems to fail to obtain the $marginTop value.

```
const Img = styled.img<{$marginTop : number | undefined}>`

    margin-top: ${({ $marginTop }) => ($marginTop ?  "calc($marginTop*-10)vh" : "0px")};

`
```

What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Wrap the value `calc(${$marginTop}*-10)`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox do you mean `margin-top: ${({ $marginTop }) => ($marginTop ?  "calc(${$marginTop}*-100)vh" : "0")};` ?

Comment: Almost. The inner string needs to be a template string. `margin-top: ${({ $marginTop }) => ($marginTop ? \`calc(${$marginTop}*-100)vh\` : "0")};`

Comment: @evolutionxbox doesn't seem to work. the margin-top is not applied. one way i can go around is by simply doing `<Img $marginTop= {entry?.intersectionRatio *-10 }  src={imgUrl} alt="" />` but this defeats the purpose of calc function

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the backticks as some peoples have already answered in the comments.

```
margin-top: ${({ $marginTop }) => ($marginTop ? `calc(${$marginTop}*-100)vh` : "0")};
```